# Laravel query builder: group relations and count total amount

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 9 and want to create chart for user-role dependency and I need count amount of users with specific role

This is my tables (for example)

```
// users
| id  | name     |
| --- | ---      |
| 1   | John Doe |
| 2   | Not John Doe |

// roles
| id  | slug  |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | admin |
| 2   | ga    |

// role_users
| user_id | role_id |
| ------- | ------- |
| 1       | 1       |
| 2       | 1       |
| 2       | 2       |
```

I want to count users with admin role

```php
User::whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->whereSlug(Role::ADMIN()))->count()
```

It works, I get correct number but I need to do same query for another roles so this is where things become ugly. I want to avoid doing this

```php
$a = User::whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->whereSlug(Role::ADMIN()))->count(); // 2
$b = User::whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->whereSlug(Role::MODERATOR()))->count(); // 10
$c = User::whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->whereSlug(Role::GA()))->count(); // 12
$d = User::whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->whereSlug(Role::CA()))->count(); // 85
```

At the end I need to get an array of numbers like `[2, 10, 12, 85]`. How can I do it using Laravel queries?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve similar with

```php
$users_count = DB::table('role_users')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as users_count, role_id'))
                ->groupBy('role_id')
                ->get()
                ->mapWithKeys(fn($item, $key) => [$item->role_id => $item->users_count])
                ->toArray();
```

Now I can access count array with `array_values($users_count)`